# building a function to compute correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, function, correlation

I will like to create an R-function that computes the percentage of individuals with an observation (value 1) between columns. For example, in the following data.frame:

```
id A B C
a  1 0 1
b  1 1 1
c  0 0 0
```

I would like to cross-percentage matrix that states the percentage of individuals with A and B, B and C and A and C. In this case it would be something like:

```
  A     B     C
A 1     0.33  0.66
B 0.33  1     0.33
C 0.66  0.33  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
d <- as.matrix(df[-1])
e <- t(d) %*% d/ nrow(d)
diag(e) <- 1
e
          A         B         C
A 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
B 0.3333333 1.0000000 0.3333333
C 0.6666667 0.3333333 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

We could convert subset of the data.frame to `matrix` (the numeric columns), use `crossprod` and then change the diagonal values to 1

```
m1 <- as.matrix(df1[-1])
out <- crossprod(m1)/ncol(m1)
out[row(out) == col(out)] <- 1
```

-output

```
out
#          A         B         C
#A 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
#B 0.3333333 1.0000000 0.3333333
#C 0.6666667 0.3333333 1.0000000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("a", "b", "c"), A = c(1L, 1L, 0L), B = c(0L, 
1L, 0L), C = c(1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```